# Swift return random String

Tags: arrays, swift, string, int, swiftui

Why does this work with numbers only?
I can get a random number displayed but not a random string.
How do i format it?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let results = [8, 5, 10].map(Result.init)
    let orden = ["hej", "ta", "tojj"].map(Ord.init)

    @State var randomResult: Result?
    @State var randomOrd: Ord?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {


               self.randomResult = self.results.randomElement()
                self.randomOrd = self.orden.randomElement()
            }) {
                Text("Button title, \(randomResult?.score ?? 0)")

               Text(randomOrd?.ord ?? 0)
               // THIS DOESN'T WORK even when i put an Int around it 


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value `0` is definitely not a string. The string equivalent is an empty string

```
Text(randomOrd?.ord ?? "")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Text initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3307109-init) takes `content` of type `StringProtocol`:

> `init<S>(_ content: S) where S : StringProtocol`

Note that in

```
Text("Button title, \(randomResult?.score ?? 0)")
```

you are passing a string (with interpolated int) which is valid. However, in

```
Text(randomOrd?.ord ?? 0)
```

it seems that you are trying to pass directly an int, which is invalid.

Based on the type of `ord`:

If it's a string, you should implement it as:

```
Text(randomOrd?.ord ?? "0") // OR maybe Text(randomOrd?.ord ?? "")
```

And if it's an integer:

```
Text("\(randomOrd?.ord ?? 0)")
```